# Yii2 model relation not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Other model data not showing in my Gridview.

I have 2 models,ListForms and Lists.
I want to show list name from Lists on listforms gridview.
This is my code.

ListForms Model:

```
class ListForms extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{

       // relation name
        public $listname;            

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'listForms';
    }     

  public function getListname() {   
      return $this->hasOne(Lists::classname(), ['listid' => 'listids']);                       
}
```

ListForms GridView:

```
[
 'label'=>'List Name',
 'attribute' => 'listname',
 'value' => 'listname.listname'
],
```

ListFormsSearch:

```
   public function search($params){                  
    $query = ListForms::find();
            $query->joinWith(['listname']);         
            //...           
    }
```

Comment: What is `listid` and what is `listids`? `listids` seems like there could be "more of..." and I'm just curious what is stored in the field

Comment: listid is primary key of Lists table and listids is foreign key in listForm table

Comment: Hmm then what is mentioned here seems correct to me... You should try debugging or insert the occasional `die()` here and there to see that it actually calls your `search()`-method etc.

Comment: The value in grid is not correct. You must set relation as $model->getListName()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
public $listname;
```

from the model, because you declare the variable in the model it will NOT be taken from the database and shown. Basically it will not work in a lot of places.